# Sum of product of distinct numbers and their count

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Given an array of N elements where N is up to 200000. Array elements are at max 100000. Now we are providing Q queries of form [a b]. For each query we need to tell the sum of:

```
((Count of each distinct number in range a to b)^2)*(Value of that distinct number)
```

**Example** Let N=8 and array be [1 1 2 2 1 3 1 1], and let Q=1. That means just one query. Let a=2 and b=7, then the answer is 20

**Explanation** :

```
occurrence of 1-> 3
occurrence of 2-> 2
occurrence of 3-> 1
cost=3*3*1 + 2*2*2 + 1*1*3= 20
```

Now if there were less queries than it would not have been so difficult question But Q can be up to 200000. So what must be best suited data structure for this problem ?

Comment: Are a and b constant or change for each query?

Comment: @Ari I think they change most likely

Comment: What is the expected time complexity(or time limit)?

Comment: @Ari Obviously they change

Comment: @kraskevich It can be around logN per query or something like this

Comment: @doremoon I know how to achieve `O(sqrt(n))` per query. Is it fast enough?

Comment: @kraskevich Yeah I think it will.What is it ?

Comment: @kraskevich yeah that is quite fast if its not a problem from an online judge

Comment: Either I'm not understanding your question, or your example is flawed. You say "...each distinct number in range a to b", and then "a=2" and "b=7", but then calculate an answer that includes the 1s in the list. Last time I checked, 1 was not "in the range 2 to 7"...

Comment: @twalberg 2 and 7 are array indexes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is offline an `O((n + q) * sqrt(n))` solution:

1. Let's divide the given array into `sqrt(n)` consecutive blocks with `sqrt(n)` elements each.
2. Let's divide all queries based on the number a block which contains their left border.
3. Now we will answer queries from each group individually:

   - Inside one group, we should sort the queries by their right border(in increasing order).
   - Let's iterate over all queries from this group in the sorted order and maintain the following invariant: all numbers that lie inside a block covered by this query except, maybe, the first and the last blocks, are already processed. We can maintain it by processing the next block when we need it.
   - Given this invariant, we can get the answer to this query by looking only at numbers in the first and the last block(that contain borders of this query). There are at most `O(sqrt(n))` such numbers, so we can simply iterate over them.
   - Clarification: we maintain an array `count` of size `MAX_VALUE`, where `count[i]` is the number of occurrences of `i` among the processed numbers and `curSum` - the sum of the target function for the processed numbers. We can add or remove one number in `O(1)`: increment or decrement `count[i]` and adjust `curSum`. The number was processed means that it has been taken into account in the `count` array and the `curSum` variable.

Time complexity: for each group, we traverse the array from left to right at once to process the number in inner blocks. It takes an `O(n * sqrt(n))` times. Each query gives additional `O(sqrt(n))` time for processing numbers in the first and the last block for this query. Thus, the total time complexity is `O((n + q) * sqrt(n))`.